# Fill paint inside image boundary onTouch in android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, paint

I'm creating custom view and a bitmap from drawable and drawing paint on x, y points. I'm able to draw paint, but its going outside the boundaries.

**Here's my code.**

```
package com.example.finalpaint;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class CustomView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    public Paint mPaint;
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    Bitmap bmp;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);
       setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
       // setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.human_body_front);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(30);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(mPath);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, mPaint);
        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 0;
    //Draw dw = new Draw();

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(mPath);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        if ((int) event.getX() < 1)
            return false;
        if ((int) event.getY() < 1)
            return false;
        if ((int) event.getX() > bmp.getWidth())
            return false;
        if ((int) event.getY() > bmp.getHeight())
            return false;
        int color = bmp.getPixel((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

        if(color == Color.TRANSPARENT)
            return false;
        if(color == Color.WHITE);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
```

This is MainActivity, setting content view to custom view.

```
package com.example.finalpaint;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomView view = new CustomView(this);
        setContentView(view);


    }
}
```

I want to draw paint inside of an image within the boundaries when OnTouch.

**Here is my screenshot.**

[image: 1]

Comment: Don't quote me on this but I think you'll have to loop through all the pixels and check if it's inside the black outlines. You can only fill() shapes that are drawn through code.

Comment: Could you post an screenshot of your app to describe the problem more clearly?

Comment: Can you brief, how can i do that @Jonas Giuro

Comment: I was hoping someone would prove me wrong because looping through the pixels is really slow. You'll need to have two nested for loops (for width and height of the image) and in there you getImageData() to see if you hit a border and if yes you start coloring.

Comment: @ Jonas, I'm new to android.. Can you explain me what touch_start, touch_move,touch_up methods does in my custom view.

Comment: Can anyone help me out how to loop through all the pixels and get color?

Comment: @NaveenGajula Did you managed to solve this problem ? Unfortunately I'm in the same position.